# How does Lyapunov time measure divergence?

Tags: chaos-theory

"By convention, it is defined as the time for the distance between nearby trajectories of the system to increase by a factor of e."

Okay, but in a Lorentz attractor, the distance between two time-dependent trajectories can come back into closer contact with each other, so how could this distance ever become exponentially divergent when boundedness is a needed component of chaotic behavior?

Comment: This definition is fairly informal and a proper definition would be based on the first derivatives of the dynamics.  But the main source of your confusion is that there is an implicit assumption here that you start with an infinitesimal difference in initial conditions.  In a differentiable system, the initial difference can always be made small enough that the trajectories will move apart for at least one Lyapunov time.

If the initial difference is truly infinitesimal then the boundless doesn’t pose a problem because after any finite time the difference will still be (a larger) infinitesimal

Comment: Alright that makes a little more sense then, thank you.

Comment: Just noticed a typo in my comment above: “boundless” $\to$ “boundedness”.